# Can't remove item from dynamically generated list

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble with a function that I've created using scotch.io's VueJS guide. It's supposed to remove a function from the list on click, (triggering a view update) but I keep getting this console error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "$index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in root instance)

The guide doesn't say to declare anything in the data option, what am I missing?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="event in events">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>
        {{event.name}}
      </h4>
      <h5>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" v-if="event.date"></i>
        {{event.date}}
      </h5>
      <p class="list-group-item-next" v-if="event.description">{{event.description}}</p>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteEvent($index)">Delete Event</button>
    </a>
```

And the relevant JS:

```
new Vue({

  ...

  methods: {

    ...

    deleteEvent: function(index) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?")) {
        this.events.$remove(index);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

There's already been a couple of cases where I've had to swap out deprecated directives that the guide uses, (v-repeat, v-on="click", etc) is the problem something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The guide you are following is slightly outdated.

In Vue 2.0, using the index requires a little change in the syntax:

```html
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-for="(event, index) in events">
  <!-- You have to ask for it:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteEvent(index)">
  <!-- Then use it the way you named it:                        ^^^^^ -->
    Delete Event
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, @Joseph Silber that seemed to clear up part of it. Now I'm getting this error:

    `Uncaught TypeError: this.events.$remove is not a function
       at Vue$3.deleteEvent (app.js:42)
       at Proxy.boundFn (vue.js:130)
       at Object.click [as fn] (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:8427), <anonymous>:2:2036)
       at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (vue.js:2229)`

Comment: Also, I tried refactoring the code to this as well:

    `Vue.delete(this.event, index);` 

which doesn't throw an error, but the item does not get deleted.

Comment: @Snuglas these are all separate questions, for which you should open new questions.